# Provided the first arg, replace slashes with backslashes

Tags: batch-file

Below is the .bat code I have for replacing the "/" occurrences of the first argument with "\", then executing that command with parameters %2, all redirected to %3:

```
@ECHO OFF

if exist %1 (
    set a=%1:/=\%
    %a% %2 > %3
) else (
    Echo "File not found"
)
```

The output of the above is:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What is wrong with the above? Also, how could I split the second argument (%2) into words (given that it is a sentence, ie., a collection of words)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do substring replacement with parameter variables (`%1`) or `for` variables `(%%a`), only with "normal" environment variables.

```
@ECHO OFF
if not exist "%1" goto :notfound
set "a=%~1"
set "a=%a:/=\%"
%a% %2 > %3
goto :eof
:notfound
Echo "File not found"
```

I changed your logic a bit to avoid [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thanks! The correct function from %1 seems to be invoked now. The problem is that the argument %2 is now considered as one string, but it is a collection of words that need to be squeezed between %a% and %3. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34986333/edit) your question with an example, please? May there be `/` in `%2`?

Comment: I provided a separate question, to avoid clutter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987704/split-the-passed-parameter-then-access-all-elements