# Split the passed parameter, then access all elements

Tags: batch-file

My .bat file is supposed to execute command passed as the first argument, %1, which takes a list of parameters that are contained within the second parameter passed, %2.

Note that the second file is interpreted as a sentence, but is in fact a list of words. Therefore, program %1 complains as it has access to only one element. How can I split the second argument, %2, and invoke the correct format %1 %firstArgOf1 %secondArgOf1 ...

I am interested in solutions where the number of words in %2 is know in advance, but a variant with an unknown number of words in %2 is welcome.

EXAMPLE:

Program "myProgram" accepts 6 parameters. Any other number of parameters passed results in an error:

```
myProgram "this is one sentence passed as a single parameter"
```

However, myProgram works correctly in the following:

```
myProgram this is one sentence passed as a single parameter
```

The thing is, parameter "this is one sentence passed as a single parameter" is passed a a string (and this is fixed), so I have to find a workaround in a .bat file to split this argument.

Comment: You only need to remove the quotes. Try `myProgram.exe %~1` from your batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove quotes from a parameter, you can use the syntax `%~1`.

In a batch file it looks like

```
@echo off
myProg.exe %~1
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "parm1=%~1"
SET "parmrest=%*"
CALL SET "parmrest=%%parmrest:*%~1=%%"
ECHO(command is "%parm1%" with arguments "%parmrest%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This should accomplish your partition.

Comment: Not really. The second parameter is still one big sentence (containing words that I try to pass one by one to the first parameter passed to %1).

Comment: Please provide examples.